# Jenkins matrix-based security permission for viewing User Groups

Tags: jenkins, active-directory

We are using the Active Directory (AD) plugin and granting permissions based on AD groups.  Users do not see their groups appear on the user page unless their AD group is granted the Overall Administer permission. That doesn't seem correct.

For example: Jane is in AD-group-Developers. Jane logs in and goes to her user page. No Groups show up. Then, after I add the Overall Administer permission to the AD-group-Developer, Jane sees the AD-group-Developers appear on her user page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would [open an issue](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+plugin) on their [jira page](http://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=hide&reset=true&jqlQuery=project+%3D+JENKINS+AND+status+in+%28Open%2C+%22In+Progress%22%2C+Reopened%29+AND+component+%3D+%27active-directory-plugin%27)

Comment: This is not an Active Directory problem.